# Image covering buttons even though the buttons are registered after

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a resize function so that when you press the button everything changes to a new screen size, if I remove the image the buttons appear, but as soon as I add the image no buttons are registered. the code for the placing also does execute.
(I know the code is bad this is a personal project and I don't need it to be perfect)

```
def resize_all():
    global allbtns, img, panel
    for i in allbtns:
        i.place_forget()

    img = Pimage.open(f"{pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()}/image.png")
    img = img.resize((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    panel = tkr.Label(app, image = img)
    panel.place(x = 0, y = 0)
 
    counter.place(x=round(WIDTH*.729), y=round(HEIGHT*.444))
    startbtn.place(x=round(WIDTH*.833), y=round(HEIGHT*.611))
    stopbtn.place(x=round(WIDTH*.881), y=round(HEIGHT*.611))
    savepbtn.place(x=round(WIDTH*.833), y=round(HEIGHT*.644))
    respbtn.place(x=round(WIDTH*.881), y=round(HEIGHT*.644))
    savedval.place(x=round(WIDTH*.847), y=round(HEIGHT*.68))
    infobtnp.place(x=round(WIDTH*.379), y=round(HEIGHT*.333))
    infobtnr.place(x=round(WIDTH*.407), y=round(HEIGHT*.333))
    comentsbtnp.place(x=round(WIDTH*.392), y=round(HEIGHT*.526))
    comentsbtnr.place(x=round(WIDTH*.42), y=round(HEIGHT*.526))
    folosbtnp.place(x=round(WIDTH*.236), y=round(HEIGHT*.7))
    folosbtnr.place(x=round(WIDTH*.263), y=round(HEIGHT*.7))
    drops.place(x=round(WIDTH*.784), y=round(HEIGHT*.622))
    dropm.place(x=round(WIDTH*.746), y=round(HEIGHT*.622))
```

I already tried changing the order of the registering but it still doesn't work.
If you need the whole code leave a comment and I'll send it.

Comment: Have you considered using one of the other geometry manager methods, `pack` or `grid`? You may have an easier time with those than with `place`

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve]. Not your whole program, but give us enough code to reproduce the problem. We don't need 14 other widgets, one or two should be enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the size of the image? Most likely it's simply covering the other widgets.

Comment: @BryanOakley the size of the image is the size of the screen, it is meant to be a background

Comment: @BryanOakley you are correct, the image is covering the buttons, do you know how to make it so that the image is placed at the back instead of on top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the image is covering the buttons. You can try lowering the image to the bottom of the stacking order with something like this:

```
panel.lower()
```

Arguably, a better solution is to create the image label at the same time you create the other widgets, and create it first so that that is lowest in the stacking order. Then, inside `resize_all` you can just give the existing label a different image:

```
def resize_all():
    ...
    img = Pimage.open(f"{pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()}/image.png")
    img = img.resize((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    self.panel.configure(image=img)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you, the code on the bottom fixed my issue.